# Where is my wireless interface?

Tags: networking, wireless, xubuntu, network-manager

So I've got a problem. I installed Xubuntu 18.04 last week and no wireless interface is available. :(

So I hammered around the place trying to find some solutions, tried a few like changing from 16.04 to 18.04, reinstalling the wireless module etc etc.
I have this 
[wireless debug read out](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZPXS4MTsbj/) which from the way I'm reading it:

1. I have compatible hardware Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 supported by iwlwifi module
2. the iwlwifi module is installed
3. There are no Hard or Soft blocks on the wireless card
4. I have a network manager and, as I can ssh to my laptop over cable, its working

Correct me if I'm wrong but as I have these yummies on start up should it not detect the wifi card, load the wifi module, which is then used by the network manager to create an interface which can then be used for handing network traffic?

If so my question is why isn't my wireless interface created?

I'm know I'm missing something simple here and I'm hoping some fresh eye's might see what I'm not seeing.

Comment: Great details in your paste.  Unrelated, but you can try removing `microcode` from your blacklist.  Is `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` default?  I've never used it, but it seems the `0280` does indeed use `iwlwifi`.  Am I missing/can you provide any related output from `dmesg`?

Comment: Edit your question and post  output of the command `ip addr show`

Comment: well thanks for the help. dmesg is showing that the card is not being powered. With the system clock being reset on boot I'm now thinking there something funky happening with boot, going to try and change BIOS. If I do get it working at some point I'll post what I done.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some issues with NetworkManager and (I think) systemd, especially when updating older systems.  I've found that by playing with `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, I can fix a few issues.

First, if I do *not* declare the interfaces in `/etc/interfaces` (which we should not do with NetworkManager), then we must also have:

```
[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

To fix issues with NetworkManager and my wireless card (which uses `wl`), I've had to add the following to prevent issues:

```
[device-mac-randomization]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

This second entry helps when I see that NetworkManager thinks *the device is not ready*.